# JWPlayer invalid license key error code (100012)

Tags: java, android, video, jwplayer

I am trying to play a Video using JWPlayer and getting **invalid license key error code (100012)** after player setup.

[image]

Using free developer account on JWplayer dashboard and got license key from dashboard -> players -> Downloads & Keys section.

**JW player Android Sdk version: 3.0.0**

Integration Steps:

> 1. Downloaded Android JW Player SDK
> 2. Added dependency in android studio as .aar
> 3. Configured the license key in manifest file
> 4. Added a player to an adapter using recycler view.
> 5. Run the app and got the invalid license key error in JWplayer view.

**We can find license key from dashboard -> tools section but I could not see tools in dashboard for free account. So, tools section enabled for paid account only?**

Comment: JW Player only exposes the SDK license key for non-free accounts

Comment: Even I am stuck with the same, according to the document this error only appears when Licence key is invalid. However I am using the same key for iOS which is working. If anyone is solved this issue please ping here.

Answer (score 0):

Add inside your `Application` class `onCreate` method

```
LicenseUtil.setLicenseKey(this, "YOUR_LICENSE_KEY")
```